# Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc; version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, tomcat9, liferay-7.3

I have downloaded [Liferay 7.3.5 Community Edition from here](https://www.liferay.com/downloads-community) and trying to deploy a HelloWorld portlet for testing purposes. It is bundled with Tomcat.
I am using Liferay Developer Studio (the same old Eclipse on steroids) for developing and deploying the portlet. Version 3.8.1.202004240132-ga2
I have also created a Server like in [this link](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018158951-Installing-a-Server-in-Liferay-Developer-Studio-) - the server is using the tomcat 9.0.37 from the already downloaded bundle.

After steps above, I have followed steps from [here](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018156851-Starting-Module-Development) to create a Module Project and to deploy it on the already started tomcat server. The portlet appears in the deployed section, but with a red "x" near it:
[image]

I went to add the portlet/widget in a widget page that I have created for this purpose, but I could not find the portlet:
[image]

Then, logged in with an admin user, I went to Control Panel -> App Manager and searched for my Portlet. It appears as "Installed" and I can activate it. After I hit "Activate", Eclipse logs start writing: `ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-8][PortletServlet:119] javax.portlet.PortletException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: VictorTestPortlet [2716]_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc; version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"_ [Sanitized]`

[image]

**The Question**: what is causing this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found the complex solution yourself, there are two simpler ways:

1. Use the target platform. Assuming you're using Liferay Workspace, your gradle.properties in the root of your workspace has an entry `liferay.workspace.target.platform.version`. Set it to `7.3.5` and the versions will be taken automagically
2. Have even the required modules be detected automagically by setting the target platform, and declare your dependency as

   dependencies {
   compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "release.portal.api"
   }

This will even figure out the exact module (of more than 1000) that you need to depend on. Granted, it kind of works against the whole concept of modularization (to be aware of your dependencies), but it's soooo convenient.

Comment: In Liferay's case, being aware of the dependency versions basically boils down to the question "which exact module versions are deployed on the target liferay server?" and that is a HUGE task on upgrade. Setting a central target platform version answers this question for all liferay modules you depend on. So, I would not say that it works against the concept of modularization -- it just answers that one repeated question in one line.

Comment: As I said: Sooooooo convenient. At the price of omitting the explicit dependencies (in case 2). Option #1 still gives you the explicit dependencies with an automagically determined version number. Already quite good but way less convenient in case a module that you depend on changes names or is broken up into multiple modules.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is as it is already stated - the dependency is not found.

To fix this, I went in *build.gradle* file that is missing a version for the "com.liferay.portal" dependency. So, my line was looking like this:

```
compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel"
```

And now it is looking like this:

```
compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "9.8.1"
```

The version **MUST** be the same as found in your Liferay Server instance - you can find it by accessing the `portal-kernel.jar` and looking into its MANIFEST.MF file for the key "Bundle-Version". The jar is located in ...portal-tomcat-7.3.5\tomcat-9.0.37\lib\ext folder.

Good luck !